# why this is wrong about using for_each?

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::ostream_iterator;
int main()
{
    vector<int> vec_int{ 1,2,3 };
    std::for_each(vec_int.crbegin(), vec_int.rend(), [](const int & i) { cout << i;});
    return 0;
}
```

Error is:

> C2782: '_Fn1 std::for_each(_InIt,_InIt,_Fn1)': template parameter '_InIt' is ambiguous

who can tell how to using for_each correctly?

Comment: Please provide in your question the exact error, not a screenshot of it.

Comment: Make sure you are using C++11. lambda functions are supported supported in prior versions. if you are using g++, you need to use `-std=c++11` in the command line.

Comment: I found it worked,if I replace`vec_int.crbegin()`with `vec_int.rbegin()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mixing `const` and non-`const` iterators. Those are different types, thus template argument deduction fails. Use either one of them for both arguments:

```
std::for_each(vec_int.crbegin(), vec_int.crend(), [](const int & i) { cout << i;});
                                         ^
```

Answer (score 4):

`for_each` requires same iterators type, you provide a `const_reverse_iterator` and `reverse_iterator`.

Using `crend` as second parameter fixes your issue:

```
std::for_each(vec_int.crbegin(), vec_int.crend(), [](const int & i) { cout << i;});
```